# How to reduce number of segments in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a two node elasticsearch cluster which is configured to have 5 shards and 2 replicas. After I indexed a db table with ~2M records, there are 124 segments generated under the corresponding cache. This number is too big, and I am afraid it would easily reach the hard limit of nofiles with more indices added.

Is there a way to reduce the number of segments per index? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have control over [merge policy](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/merge.html) in elasticsearch. The merge settings can be updated dynamically using [Update Index Settings API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings.html). You can, for example, reduce `index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier` to some value below 10 and this will reduce the number of segments on each tier and, as a result, the total number of segments.

You can also force merge manually using [Optimize API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-optimize.html). For example:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/your-index/_optimize?max_num_segments=1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that should work. I added "-Des.max-open-files=true" in elasticsearch command line trying to see the maximum allowed nofiles for it. But when I started the process, the log says "max_open_files [0]". This is really confusing, do you know why this happens and how can I get that information correctly?

Comment: To test the number of open files, elasticsearch is trying to create as many files as it can in the `work\open_files` directory which is located in the elasticsearch home directory. Could it be possible that the user you are running elasticsearch under doesn't have enough privileges to create this directory?

Comment: imotov, thanks for the updates. I think if elasticsearch is using this way to detect the "max no. fp", it is probably a bad idea. For my process, I set the soft limit equal to the hard limit for the elasticsearch process, so the way elasticsearch does testing would probably mess up other running process which has files opened. Would it be better to just check /proc/<pid>/limits?

Comment: It might not be perfect, but elasticsearch tries to be platform-independent and there are many platforms out there where checking /proc/<pid>/limits wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the max number of segments using the following command

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=5'
```

in case of windows you will need to remove the inverted commas.

Comment: Is this change permanent? I mean if you force merge the index with `max_num_segments=5`, segments will never increase?